# javascript alert giving different number

Tags: javascript, jquery, alert

Consider the following JavaScript code:

```
alert(9999999999999999);
```

When I am executing this file, I get the following output:

[image: alert message]

Why I am getting `100000000000`  in `alert()`? Can anyone give suggestions please?

Comment: The maximum number in JS is 9007199254740992

Comment: if u want to print it then put inside qoute

Comment: @willem Dhaeseleer if the number exceeds the max number ....is there any alternatives to display that number.

Comment: Watch this talk, it will tell you all you ever need to know about IEEE 754 number implementations. A MUST WATCH for programmers, really: Bartek Szopka: Everything you never wanted to know about JavaScript numbers -- JSConf EU 2013; http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MqHDDtVYJRI

Comment: Try: alert("9999999999999999"); That will probably work. 
No clue why this doesn't work, cause it should! As you will notice when working with javascript, some things are really curious.

When i have to say a reason out of my head, i think its a compile error in javascript itself. Probably something to do with number being to big for integer and a misinterpretation with casting.

Comment: but it treats as a string @PatrickAleman

Comment: Thats even more curious. Did you test it?

Comment: There are a number of libraries for JavaScript like https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/ (Google 'javascript big integer decimal number' to find many others).

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with the way JavaScript deals with numbers. The largest possible integer value in JavaScript is 9007199254740992.

To compare:

Your number: 9007199254740992
Largest num: 9999999999999999

So if you test 9007199254740992 it will work fine, but one number more (9007199254740993) and JavaScript will return 9007199254740992 still.

To give further detail, JavaScript numbers are 64-bit floating point values, the largest exact integral value is 2<sup>53</sup>.

Answer (score 0):

It's represented as double, and that number cannot be stored *exactly* as a double because it has too many significant digits.  The result you got back is the closest double that can be represented.

See http://babbage.cs.qc.cuny.edu/IEEE-754.old/64bit.html